# Showing ${Mf(z) \over 10M - f(z)}$ is bounded if $\text{Re}(f(z)) < M$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Data:** Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $\Omega - \{a\}$.  Suppose further that $\text{Re}(f(z)) < M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Define $g(z)$ as follows:

$$
g(z) = {Mf(z) \over 10M - f(z)}
$$

Since $\text{Re}(f(z)) < M$, we have that the denominator of $g(z)$ is never zero on $\Omega$ so that $g(z)$ is analytic on $\Omega$.

**Question:** How do we show that $g(z)$ is bounded by a constant?

**Attempt:**

$$
|g(z)| = \left|{M f(z) \over 10M - f(z)}\right| = {|Mf(z)| \over |10M - f(z)|} \le {|Mf(z)| \over |9M|} \le {1 \over 9} |f(z)|
$$

which doesn't quite do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\dfrac{M f}{10 M - f} = -M + \dfrac{c}{10 M - f}$$
for some constant $c$

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Israel

We have that

$$
|g(z)| =  {|Mf(z)| \over |10M - f(z)|}  = \underbrace{|-M| + {|10M^2| \over |10M - f(z)|}}_{\text{via (*) below}} \le {10M^2 \over 9M} + M = {10 \over 9} M + M < 3M 
$$

via

\begin{equation*}
\tag{*}
{M f(z) \over 10M - f(z)} = {-M(10M - f(z)) + 10M^2 \over 10M - f(z)} =  -M + {10M^2 \over 10M - f(z)}
\end{equation*}

However, I have independent reason to believe this bound can actually be made less than $M$ (as opposed to $3M$ below).  How to show this?

Comment: What does $w \mapsto \frac{M\cdot w}{10M-w}$ map the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} w < M$ to?

Comment: Well, I know the answer is into the ball with radius $|M|$; however, I don't know why. :)